# How to automate high resolution renders in bulk

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I have to render a large number of images at 8k resolution.
but blender takes a very long time to render a single image.
If I split an image into different parts then it renders one image with in minutes.
  But the problem is I have to render these images in bulk. Is there a quick and efficient way to handle this problem?

Comment: You can find an example of splitting a render [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38223109/2684771) you just need to add another loop to do the same for multiple frames, if you are talking about multiple blend files then an external script could be used to run the script on each file.

Comment: I think it is important to realize that if you double the render dimensions, you quadruple the number of pixels that need to be rendered. This is probably the explanation for the nonlinear increase in render times you are seeing with the increase of resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering at 8k should not be problem for blender.

Rendering several small samples first is **not** faster than just rendering the whole thing.

A solution for your large amount of 8k renderings could be sheepit https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/index.php you can use it to have other people render your projects, or you could check the setting that allows only you to render it. All you have to do is upload your blend files and click a few buttons. (I'm not going to provide a step by step tutorial because there are thousands of easy to find tutorials on youtube like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0M8hO6k8Kqs)